# Strange python behaviour of f.write()

Tags: python

I was writing some python code and I found a strange behaviour in my code.

This is the code:

```
import sys

f=open("test1","wb")
test="1000000000"
f.write(bytearray(int(test)))
f.close()
```

It generates the file **test1** with lenght 1000000000 (1,0 GB) filled with 0.
Is this supposed to happen(if yes, **why**?) or is a bug?

Comment: Do you know what the first argument to `bytearray` is supposed to be?

Comment: Reading [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytearray) is overrated, isn't it?

Comment: What did you even _expect_ to happen, anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `bytearray()` function creates an array of bytes from a parameter `source` and the documentation states:

> If it is an integer, the array will have that size and will be initialized with null bytes.

So you are then just writing 1 billion null characters (`\x00`) to that file!

Answer (score 0):

Initialising a `bytearray` with a single integer value creates an empty (i.e. filled with zeroes) `bytearray` of the size specified (as [documented here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytearray)). Your code therefore converts the string "1000000000" into an integer and then creates a `bytearray` of that size which it writes to disk.

There is nothing strange or surprising about this behaviour.